# Android Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, php, android, encryption

There are many encryption algorithms and most of them require **IV** and **KEY** and **Plaintext**.

In Android, we have to add 3 of them to our code. On the other side, Android is open source and everyone can extract APK files and access the **IV** and the **KEY** , this doesn't make it secure.

Which algorithms are better and unbreakble that can be applied in Java and PHP. I'm working on a Project similar to Instagram/Facebook/Twitter, Security is the first problem for such applications.

Comment: It is difficult to recommend a solution to your problem without you clearly defining your threat model - what are you trying to protect, who from and why?  I have a feeling that this is simply going to boil down to "use HTTPS".

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Generally i want to keep everything encrypted without IV and KEY. HTTPS doesnt solve the problem when you're posting ID from an Android app to the server. ID must not be changeable by Users. That's why i want to encrypt it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't encrypt the ID *server-side* and then give that to the client to store?  Some more information would really help, I still don't fully understand the scenario.

Comment: use the `JNI` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with basic stuff:

- never store an IV/KEY in the source code or unencrypted within the app filesystem
- your might want to look into the Android KeyStore and it's supported operations
- you might need to depend upon the existence of a hardware keystore (so that users cannot modify locally stored keys)

For more information I would recommend to look into the [OWASP MSTG](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg) -- Android Data Store and Android Cryptographic APIs might be interesting to you

Comment: You must be able to recover IV in order to decrypt later. No harm in making it public